# How to handly arbitrary json objects with spring mvc?

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

I successfully use spring-mvc with json in order to convert between domain objects and json objects.

Now, I want to write a Controller that just accepts any json, validates it and provides it in a compact serialisable form for the service layer. (The json string would be sufficient, any compact byte array representation better). My current approch is this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{key}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Object getDocument(@PathVariable("username") String username,
        @PathVariable("key") String key,
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
    LOGGER.info(createAccessLog(request));
    Container doc = containerService.get(username, key);
    return jacksonmapper.map(doc.getDocument(), Map.class);
}
```

and

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{key}", method=RequestMethod.PUT)
public void putDocument(@PathVariable("username") String username,
        @PathVariable("key") String key,
        @RequestBody Map<String,Object> document,
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
    LOGGER.info(createAccessLog(request));
    containerService.createOrUpdate(username, key,document);
}
```

Note that this approach does not work because I don't want a Map in the put method and the get method returns just {"this":null};. How do I have to configure my methods?

Cheers,

Jan

Answer (score 2):

Spring has this functionality automatically. You just need `<mvc:annotation-driven />` and jackson on your classpath. Then spring will handle all requests with accept header set to `*/json`, and respective responses, through the JSON mapper.

Comment: Bozoho, the JSON mapping is not the problem but what method signature do I need to get a generic json object which I can serialize? I currently only work with public void put(@RequestBody MySpecificBean bean) to get a bean from JSON.

Comment: well, how will you afterward handle the arbitrary object?

Comment: Late answer, was on vacation; I only want to serialize it and store it in a database. The client can later request it from the server. So any String/byte[]/Stream is sufficient it just should be compact.

Answer (score 0):

Its easy. You don't need the `@RequestBody` annotation.

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/{key}", method=RequestMethod.PUT)
    public void putDocument(@PathVariable("username") String username,
            @PathVariable("key") String key, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        try {
            String jsonString = IOUtils.toString(request.getInputStream()); 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        LOGGER.info(createAccessLog(request));
        containerService.createOrUpdate(username, key,document);
    }
```

Comment: I'd probably rather use ```@RequestBody byte[]``` today.